# How to sort files by type in ido

Tags: ido, ido-find-file

I've seen a tip several times that `ido-file-extensions-order` can be used to easily order files. Setup is straightforward (code at bottom), but these filetypes are only given preference when choosing between two otherwise identical files.  Is there a way to order files based on type in the minibuffer (or any way other than alphabeticaly?).

```el
(setq ido-file-extensions-order '(".org" ".py" ".txt" ".cpp" ".tex")
      ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(ido-mode 1)
```

Comment: `ido-file-extensions-order` variable is used to customize the order in which files are sorted when Ido displays them in the minibuffer. Isn't there a difference in the minibuffer when you try to open a file with and without this setting?

Comment: @Nsukami_ Thank you, I just realized that there is a large discrepancy between what I thought that variable would do, and what it does.  (the webpages I've read, eg [here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/introduction-to-ido-mode) incorrectly state it sorts the order.  It actually gives preference to filetypes when there are two otherwise identical files.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code on the [emacswiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings#toc25) allows a custom sort order, based on modification time. I've modified it to sort based on file extensions in `ido-file-extensions-order`.

```el
;; sort ido filelist by extension instead of alphabetically
(require 'cl)
(defun ido-sort-extension ()
  " sort ido file names by extension "
  (setq ido-temp-list
        (sort ido-temp-list 
              (lambda (a b)
                (< (order-file-extension a)
                   (order-file-extension b)))
              ))
  (ido-to-end  ;; move . files to end (again)
   (delq nil (mapcar
              (lambda (x) (and (char-equal (string-to-char x) ?.) x))
              ido-temp-list))))

(defun order-file-extension (name)
  " helper function to sort files by extension with ido"
  (or
   (and (file-directory-p name) -1) ;list directories first
   (cl-position t (mapcar (lambda (str)
                            (string= str (concat "." (file-name-extension name))))
                          ido-file-extensions-order))
   (+ 1 (length ido-file-extensions-order))))
(add-hook 'ido-make-file-list-hook 'ido-sort-extension)
```